# Gated integrator IC, non continuous

Tags: integrated-circuit, microchip, asic, integrator

Can anyone give me any suggestions for some good gated voltage integrators that aren't continuous, and more like a boxcar integrator?   I want to integrate the the total voltage across a pulse coming out of a PMT in around a 10ns interval, and sample that interval once at the end.

I think, perhaps, something like this: http://www.thinksrs.com/products/sr250.html but can't seem to easily find IC chips for that purpose-- could I get some pointers please? Many thanks!

EDIT: thanks for the comments, I'll have a periodic source to know when to reset after 10ns.

Comment: Is the integration time always near \$10\:\text{ns}\$? What kind of source do you have to tell when to reset and then start the interval?

Comment: I suspect you'll want a current mode PMT if you are integrating. The voltage mode PMTs are nice but in the application implied by your need here they would seem less appropriate to me. Perhaps you know better, though.

Comment: Sounds like you want a switched-capacitor filter/integrator.